# How to work "ObjectAnimator.ofFloat" from API level 14

Tags: android, animation

Since `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat` works from ***API 21***, is there any alternative or way to work `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat` for ***lower API***?

Comment: Have you tried NineOldAndroid library?

Comment: There are two `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat()` versions that work from at least API 14. Use those instead, in an [`AnimatorSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html), if needed.

Comment: and one of those two versions works from API 11